# Why does adding an ImageSpan to a Snackbar's action text work on Android devices SDK level 26 but not on SDK level 25?

Tags: android, spannablestring, android-snackbar, snackbar, spannablestringbuilder

I want to show a `Snackbar` and use an image instead of text for the action.

I use the following code:

```
    val imageSpan = ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.star)
    val builder = SpannableStringBuilder(" ")
    builder.setSpan(
        imageSpan,
        0,
        1,
        SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.container), "Hello Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .setAction(builder) {}.show()
```

`drawable_star` being a vector graphic asset, but the same happens with a `png`.

On an Android device lvl 26 and above this yields:

[image: pic1]

as expected, whereas on device lvl 25 the image is not visible:

[image: pic2]

Does someone know the reason for this and if there a workaround?

PS: You can check out my test project here: https://github.com/fmweigl/SpannableTest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to the `textAllCaps` bug on versions prior to Oreo. That `Button`'s default style will have that attribute set to `true`, which simply causes the `Button`'s text to be converted to all uppercase. That conversion is done with the platform `AllCapsTransformationMethod` class, which, on Nougat 7.1 and below, would treat everything as flat `String`s, essentially stripping any formatting spans you've set.

The fix is to turn that attribute off, and handle any uppercase conversion you might need yourself, in code. `Snackbar` offers the `snackbarButtonStyle` attribute as a means to style the action `Button`, and we can create a simple style to modify that value. For example, from your `styles.xml`:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/NoCapsButton</item>>
</style>

<style name="NoCapsButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

<sub>(If you're using a Material Components theme, the `parent` for `NoCapsButton` should instead be `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar`.)</sub>

---

In this specific case, that's all you need to do, since there's no text to convert.